# Indicate status of AJAX-request in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I created my site with Django and choose JQuery for Ajax requests.

I want to have an HTML-element indicate the status of my ajax-request and want to show it 3 things:

1. when input field is changed and request is not sent (e.g. turn button red)
2. when browser starts the ajax request (e.g. turn yellow)
3. when browser received the request and made changes in the browser

I choose a button-element for this.
I thought to change the color in a change-function to read and then send the AJAX-request.
After that $.ajax-function I thought to change it to yellow.
At the end of my fired success function, I change it back to green.

I have an input-type time and in Chrome it renders with up/down arrows. There is a kind of debounce-function in the browser when clicking several times to change the time several steps. But I think the problem occurs also when changing it by typing at a time.
The AJAX-Request works as expected, but the button never turns red or yellow.

```
ajax.js
-------
$("input.fire, select.fire").change(function() {
    var time = $("#element1").val();

    $.when(function() {
    $("#status-button").css('backgroundColor', 'red')

    $.ajax({
      url: '../../../ajax-send/',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        'time': time
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: successResponse
    })
    $("#status-button").css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
}

function successResponse(data) {
    $("#answer-div").html(data['answer']);
    $("#status-button").css('backgroundColor', 'green')
}
```

Comment: There is no matching `});` to your `$.when(function{`. Is that a typo? Also, are there any errors in your console?

Comment: `$.when` needs `.then` or `.done`. Why not use `beforeSend` inside `$.ajax` to set the yellow color?

Comment: Sorry I missed to copy the `}).done(` before my `$ajax`. There are no errors in my console.

Comment: @yezzz Thank you. I added `beforeSend:function() {$("status-button").css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');},` but it didn't work. Even to color it red in the $when-part doesn't work.